# Не кликаются пункты подменю

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, javascript

Проблема заключается в том, что на ПК все отлично работает. Т.е. горизонтальное ниспадающее меню открывается и выбирается пункт меню. Ну и, следовательно, переходим на страницу, куда ведет этот пункт меню. Но если открыть сайт на iPad, то меню раскрывается без проблем, но выбрать пунктик подменю я не могу. 
P.S. Сайт на bootstrap. Ссылку на сайт дать не могу, только выделенные IP там работают.

Comment: Плохо сформулирован вопрос. Единственный ответ "телепаты в отпуске". Где скрины? Код?

Comment: Скрины только, пожалуйста, не надо, просто сделайте fiddle.